# How to search Stored Procedures by table name being used using .net?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I need to find all saved procedures which contain specific table name. I have done that - but now going into deep, table name code in found procedure should not be commented.

Lets' say  I need to find SQL table `"TableA"` and

- I am getting matching saved procedures `"SP1"` and `"SP2"`
- But `"TableA"` in `"SP1"` is commented.

So find result should be `"SP2"` only.

Please let me know any ideas how to do this using c#?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1- using dependency**
You could use the system table `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`

This query returns a list of all procedures and the tables they are refering to.
I do not know how reliable this is. If the table is not existing at compile time or the table is rebuilt the link might be lost.

```
select o.name ProcName, referenced_entity_name TableName from sysobjects o
join sys.sql_expression_dependencies d on d.referencing_id = o.id 
where referenced_class_desc = 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' and o.type = 'P'
```

**Solution 2- using the source code**
The source code for the procedure could be found in the tabe syscomments, but splitted up in 8K chunks (i belive).

1. Read the result of this query
2. Concatenate all "text"-columns for each proc in the result order
3. Use C# to search through the code and you should be able to look for commenting key characters to keep track on the commenting-out status.

```
select o.Name,text from sysobjects o
join sys.syscomments c on c.id = o.id
where type = 'P'
order by o.name, c.colid
```